# Is there an API for managing testers for Firebase App Distribution?

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I'm wondering if there is some sort of API I can call that lets me pass testers to either add or remove?

I want to call the same code as what happens when you upload a CSV (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/manage-testers)).. but with less CSV and more Restful HTTP API (or equivalent).

I could spend some time reverse engineering what happens (and believe me, I have been trying to), but alas I have had no eureka moment yet.

Thanks!

If I find an answer before someone else does, I'll be sure to post back here.

Comment: Please file a feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 4):

Firebase App Distribution now has a REST API that includes endpoints to [add](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/app-distribution/rest/v1/projects.testers/batchAdd) and [remove](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/app-distribution/rest/v1/projects.testers/batchRemove) testers. Check out the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/app-distribution/rest) for the complete list of available endpoints.

Comment: Too late to say. Just a suggestion for implementing something like this. Could be using an invite link. With this, it's easy to add testers. Managing the testers, like adding to a group or removing could be done via the API or admin console.